# Force a single user to open files in Office Online apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps

A single user in my organization needs to be only able to open sharepoint-online files via browser apps. The file opening settings for the site are set to "open with desktop apps", since all other users must use the desktop apps.

Is there a way I can force this single user to open files via browser, without having him go and select "open in browser" every single time?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, "open with desktop apps" works for at least one library, it cannot be set for a single user.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I was afraid this would be the case... oh well!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: This is so insanely silly. Why would you ever want this as a library setting, and not a per-user setting?

Comment: @DennisK, because Microsoft decided that everyone using their products must follow the microsoft-developed patterns of work as the most efficient method of accomplishing any sort of business-related task. If you don't agree with Microsoft's way of doing business tasks, try and do something that isn't in lock-step with their methods and you'll spend your time looking for a solution and shaking your head wondering why something so amazingly obvious and useful is impossible in a Microsoft product. Like Smooth-Scrolling in Excel. 30 years of complaints on MS's UserVoice website.